# elastic search not fetching records if inserted by another application

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a wierd issue

When I insert records into Elastic search and search for it , it works as long as the insertion and search are done by the same application

My search query code is below

```
 SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices("occindex")
                .withPageable(new PageRequest(0,occurrenceQueryInput.getNoOfRecords()))
                .withQuery(matchQuery("title",occurrenceQueryInput.getTitle()))
                .withHighlightFields(new HighlightBuilder.Field("title")
                        .preTags("<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>").postTags("</span>")
                        .fragmentSize(250)
                        .numOfFragments(3))
                .build();
```

If i try to insert the records from another application into elastic search and try to do a search using Spring ElasticSearchTemplate , it does not fetch any records.

Am I doing something wrong in this code ?

I also tried refreshing the index using the below code

```
template.refresh(Employee.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not doing it right .
I was using the wrong class in the NativeSearchQueryBuilder .

Please ignore this question